# How to automatically attach device information to new email with MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, swift, testflight, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

If you use TestFlight to send Beta Feedback, it automatically attaches a file called `device_information.txt` and this includes some basic information about the device.

I want to make a support button in my app, and I'm using `MFMailComposeViewController` to create a new email. How can I retrieve (or create) the `device_information.txt` file, and then attach it to a new email?

This is an example of what the `device_information.txt` file would contain:

```
App Information:
App Name: [App Name Here]
App Version: 1.0
Installed App Version: 1.0

Device Information:
Device: iPhone6,2
iOS Version: 12.1.2
Language: en-AU (English)
Carrier: [Carrier Here]
Timezone: [Timezone Here]
Architecture: N/A
Connection Status: Cellular data
Paired Apple Watch: N/A
```

How does TestFlight achieve this? It must be possible, so if anyone can guide me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What's your issue exactly ? Attache a file to a mail? Retrieve some of these data?

Comment: The `device_information.txt` file seems to be compiled by TestFlight. I'd like to know whether it's possible to retrieve the same file and then attach it to a new email. OR retrieve some data and make my own text file and then attach that to a new email.

Comment: You'd have to do your own file I'd say.

Comment: Okay, do you know how I would be able to 1. make a custom file based on the device's information. 2. attach that to a new email.

Comment: There are question of StackOverflow for each of the lines (separate ones), I think, and also for how to attach file to mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find most of this information in UIDevice class 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice

You can than append the needed information to the mail text like this :

```
   MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
   controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   [controller setMessageBody:"your message here" isHTML:NO];
```

or using attachment like this:

```
    [controller addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"test.txt"];
```

in Swift:

```
let controller = MFMailComposeViewController()
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self
controller.setMessageBody("My message", isHTML:false)
controller.addAttachmentData(data as Data, mimeType: "text/plain", fileName: "test.txt")
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. Could you also provide `addAttachmentData` for Swift?